# How to prevent same id inserting data into database (Multi user)

Tags: duplicates

my problem is HOW CAN I PREVENT duplication of ID into mydatabase when two or more user (multi users) have to encode simultaneously, when i tried to test saving data together at the same time i always go duplicate id. im using mysql.

Comment: Hello. Please see [ask] for what makes a good question. As it stands, this question needs considerably more detail in order to be answerable.

Comment: Is the ID set to autoincrement, or is this a legitimate race condition?

Comment: It is set to race condtion. because im assigning ID for each transaction i have to produce new Id for each newly encoded Data, or group of data

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to database locking. What you need to do lock the database for writing so that only one session can access the database at a time, and prevent anyone else from writing until the first session has finished. See this info on database locking https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html